# Bash Script Variable Scope Issue

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scope

```
username="hello"
password="3333"

function login {
    # 1 - Username
    # 2 - Password
    match=0
    cat LoginsMaintMenu.txt | while read line; do
            x=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
            y=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
            if [ "${x}" == "${1}" ] && [ "${y}" == "${2}" ]; then
                    echo "match"
                    match=1
                    echo $match
                    break
            fi
    done
    echo $match
    return $match
}

echo $username $password
login ${username} ${password}
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "FAIL"
else
echo "success"
fi
```

output:

```
hello 3333
match
1
0
FAIL
```

THE PROBLEM:
I don't understand why it is echoing "fail".  the "match" variable gets set to 1 inside the while loop, but for some reason once I am out of the while loop it still thinks it is the initial zero from its declaration.

I have tried doing a lot of different things, so if someone could give me something concrete to try that'd be great!

Thanks

Comment: the `while read` is executed in a sub-shell, so any modifications you make are not passed to the parent. One of the many annoyances of bash scripting.

Comment: @MikeWeller Since bash supports [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), a pipeline is never needed.

Comment: The convention is that a return value of 0 represents success, and non-zero represents failure.  It is a *very* bad idea to ignore that convention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is actually the [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html). In bash, the right side of a pipeline is ran inside of a sub-shell. Any variables set inside of a sub shell will not be set in the parent shell. To fix this, use redirection instead of a pipeline:

```
username="hello"
password="3333"

function login {
    # 1 - Username
    # 2 - Password
    match=0
    while read x y _; do
        if [ "${x}" == "${1}" ] && [ "${y}" == "${2}" ]; then
            echo "match"
            match=1
            echo $match
            break
        fi
    done < LoginsMaintMenu.txt
    echo $match
    return $match
}

echo $username $password
if login "${username}" "${password}"; then
    echo "FAIL"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

Comment: @dan It puts the first field of the line in x, the second in y, and discards the rest of the line. It's the equivalent of the `awk` assignments in the question, without the need for awk.

Comment: Note that because the original code flaunts the convention of returning 0 for success, you should remove the `!` in the `if`, or swap the strings `FAIL` and `success`.

Answer (score 2):

The `while read ...` part of your code (that gets its input from the `cat` pipe) runs in a subshell. Changes to variables inside that are not visible outside that subshell.

To work around that, change your loop to:

```
while read ... ; do
  ...
done < LoginsMaintMenu.txt
```

Comment: I didn't know who posted first! so I gave accepted answer to the other guy cuz he has less points ;)  Thanks a lot for answering though!

Comment: jordanm's answer is also more complete - it avoids your two awkward `awk`s. You should certainly accept his answer (who posted first is unimportant).