# Variable scope for bash shell scripts and functions in the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm a little confused with my script regarding functions, variable scope, and possibly subshells.
I saw in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390635/bash-script-variable-scope-issue) that pipes spawn a subshell and the parent shell can't access variables from the subshell.  Is this the same case with cmds run in backticks too?

To not bore people, I've shortened my 100+ line script but I tried to remember to leave in the important elements (i.e. backticks, pipes etc).  Hopefully I didn't leave anything out.

```
global1=0
global2=0
start_read=true

function testfunc {
   global1=9999
   global2=1111
   echo "in testfunc"
   echo $global1
   echo $global2
}

file1=whocares
file2=whocares2

for line in `cat $file1`
do
   for i in `grep -P "\w+ stream" $file2 | grep "$line"`   # possible but unlikely problem spot
   do
         end=$(echo $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 | cut -d ',' -f 1)   # possible but unlikely spot
         duration=`testfunc $end`       # more likely problem spot
   done
done

echo "global1 = $global1"
echo "global2 = $global2"
```

So when I run my script, the last line says global1 = 0.  However, in my function testfunc, global1 gets set to 9999 and the debug msgs print out that within the function at least, it is 9999.

Two questions here:

1. Do the backticks spawn a subshell and thus making my script not
   work?
2. How do I work around this issue?

Comment: 1. Yes they do  2. Quick fix: remove the backticks and move the assignment in the function definition. Alternatively write global1= ` testfunc $end `

Comment: As an aside, those nested `for` loops look really twisted and inefficient. I guess you are trying to say `grep -P "\w+ stream" "$file2" | grep -f "$file1" | while read i; do`...

Comment: @damienfrancois, thx for your reply.  testfunc modifies several global vars.  I guess that's one thing I forgot to include.

Comment: ok, then you can try replacing `duration= \` testfunc $end \`` with simply `testfunc $end` and adding `duration=...` in the body of the function. You can really think of bash functions as macro that are simply expanded inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
global1=0
global2=0
start_read=true

function testfunc {
   global1=9999
   global2=1111
   echo "in testfunc"
   echo $global1
   echo $global2
   duration=something
}

file1=whocares
file2=whocares2

for line in `cat $file1`
do
   for i in `grep -P "\w+ stream" $file2 | grep "$line"`   # possible but unlikely problem spot
   do
         end=$(echo $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 | cut -d ',' -f 1)   # possible but unlikely spot
         testfunc $end       # more likely problem spot
   done
done

echo "global1 = $global1"
echo "global2 = $global2"
```

Comment: Difference to the script of the OP: **(1)** `duration=something` has been added to the function body; **(2)** `duration=\`testfunc $end\`` in the loop has been changed to `testfunc $end`

Answer (score 3):

> `Do the backticks spawn a subshell and thus making my script not work?`:

Yes they do and any changes made in variable in a subshell are not visible in parent shell.

> `How do I work around this issue?`

You can probably try this loop that avoid spawning a subshell:

```
while read line
do
   while read i
   do
      end=$(echo $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1-4 | cut -d ',' -f 1)
      duration=$(testfunc "$end")
   done < <(grep -P "\w+ stream" "$file2" | grep "$line")
done < "$file1"
```

PS: But `testfunc` will still be called in sub process.