# Handling variable scoping (due pipes in while loop) in POSIX shell (/bin/sh)?

Tags: linux, shell, loops, io-redirection

I have stumbled into this problem:

- [Bash Script Variable Scope Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390635/bash-script-variable-scope-issue)

> the right side of a pipeline is ran inside of a sub-shell. Any variables set inside of a sub shell will not be set in the parent shell. To fix this, use redirection instead of a pipeline:

So, here is an example script:

```sh
NUMCOUNT=0

testlines="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Duis sem sapien, congue sed lacus nec, scelerisque bibendum arcu.
Pellentesque placerat dapibus erat eu iaculis.
Maecenas vitae blandit quam.
Suspendisse eu aliquet nunc."

## this does not work - because NUMCOUNT is not preserved in a subshell - so the final line echoes $NUMCOUNT as 0, which it should not be
#echo "$testlines" | while read line; do
#  if echo "$line" | grep -m 1 -q 'que'; then
#    NUMCOUNT=$((NUMCOUNT+1))
#    echo "found match nr. $NUMCOUNT for substring 'que' in line: $line"
#  fi
#done

##this works in bash - but for dash (/bin/sh): "Syntax error: redirection unexpected"
#while read line; do
#  if echo "$line" | grep -m 1 -q 'que'; then
#    NUMCOUNT=$((NUMCOUNT+1))
#    echo "found match nr. $NUMCOUNT for substring 'que' in line: $line"
#  fi
#done <<< "$testlines"

# this works in bash - but for dash (/bin/sh): "Syntax error: redirection unexpected"
while read line; do
  if echo "$line" | grep -m 1 -q 'que'; then
    NUMCOUNT=$((NUMCOUNT+1))
    echo "found match nr. $NUMCOUNT for substring 'que' in line: $line"
  fi
done < <(echo "$testlines")

echo "Script done - found $NUMCOUNT matches"
```

If I run this in `bash`, all works fine:

```
$ bash test.sh
found match nr. 1 for substring 'que' in line: Duis sem sapien, congue sed lacus nec, scelerisque bibendum arcu.
found match nr. 2 for substring 'que' in line: Pellentesque placerat dapibus erat eu iaculis.
found match nr. 3 for substring 'que' in line: Suspendisse eu aliquet nunc.
Script done - found 3 matches
```

If I run this in `dash`, then it fails:

```
$ /bin/sh test.sh
test.sh: 31: test.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

How can I properly implement this loop in a POSIX `/bin/sh` shell, so that $NUMCOUNT is preserved for the final line of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I properly implement this loop in a POSIX /bin/sh shell, so that $NUMCOUNT is preserved for the final line of the script?

In posix, use a fifo with a background process that streams the data. But really, in your case just save the data to a file...

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
printf "%s\n" "$testlines" > "$tmp" 
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -m 1 -q 'que'; then
        ...
    fi
done < "$tmp"
rm "$tmp"
```

or using a fifo with a background process:
f

```
ifo=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$fifo"
printf "%s\n" "$testlines" > "$fifo" &
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if echo "$line" | grep -m 1 -q 'que'; then
    NUMCOUNT=$((NUMCOUNT+1))
    echo "found match nr. $NUMCOUNT for substring 'que' in line: $line"
  fi
done < "$fifo"
rm "$fifo"

echo "Script done - found $NUMCOUNT matches"
```

Also instead of running the loop in current shell, you could just save it in a variable, preprocess to extract `NUMCOUNT` and print the rest.

```
tmp=$(
    printf "%s\n" "$testlines" |
    awk -v q="'" '
    /que/{
        ++NUMCOUNT
        print "found match nr. " NUMCOUNT " for substring "q"que"q" in line: "$0
    }
    END{
        # extra last line to output NUMCOUNT
        print NUMCOUNT
    }'
)
# extract NUMCOUNT - last line
NUMCOUNT=$(printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | tail -n 1)
# extract everything except NUMCOUNT - ie. remove last line
tmp=$(printf "%s\n" "$tmp" | head -n +1)
# output the actual output
printf "%s\n" "$tmp"
# output your trailing line
printf "Script done - found %d matches\n" "$NUMCOUNT"
```

Or you could just continue execution inside the subshell.

```
printf "%s\n" "$testlines" | {
   while IFS= read -r line; do
        ...
   done
   echo "Script done - found $NUMCOUNT matches"
   # go on
}
```

Notes: [bashfaq How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [unix.stackexchange Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Fantastic @KamilCuk - thanks for these options! I generally try to avoid saving extra files, so I really appreciate the other options.